# Javaagent Why can't I debug the transform method of ClassFileTransformer in IDEA?

Tags: java, debugging, transform

I print the current thread information in the transform method,and the output is like this: `Thread[JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket,10,system]`

In other words, this transform is executed by the JDWP thread. Isn't JDWP the thread used for break points?

I’m very confused. I have two questions.

1. Why is the transform method executed by this thread?
2. Why can’t I stop at the transform method?

Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks!

Comment: What kind of transformation are we talking about? Load time transformation, for example, will be done in the thread that triggered the class loading. If this happens at a thread implementing the debug functionality, it shouldn’t be surprising that you can’t debug the debugger…

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Holger
Yes, I compiled the class file through IDEA to Hotswap during the running of the program, so I think it is Load time transformation. From what you said, I probably know the reason. I compiled the java file in the debugger, so the class loading is Triggered by the JDWP thread. Thank you so much!

One more thing I would like to know is that this is the first time I have heard the term "Load time transformation". Are there any other types of transformations?

Comment: @Holger
I changed the thread that triggers the class loading - by using remote breakpoints instead of local, now the breakpoints are hit.

It’s really hard to get tips like this, thank you for replying to my question!

Comment: “Load time” refers to the first time, a class is loaded. So when you hotswapped the class, you were already in the second category, which is called “retransformation” in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html). But it seems, the behavior and solution is similar, i.e. the retransformation also happens in the thread that triggers the redefinition. The only difference is that redefinition and in turn retransformation are limited in what they can change.